# Highlight cells with different values based on ID

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns, ID and Date. I need to highlight the rows for an ID if that ID does not have the same dates in all of the rows for that ID. e.g.:

```
ID  Date
1   1/1/2020
1   1/1/2020
1   1/1/2020
2   2/2/2020
2   2/16/2020
2   2/2/2020
```

In the case of ID = 1, it shouldn't highlight anything because all of the rows for the ID = 1 have the same dates, but in the ID = 2, there's different dates (There's 2 '2/2/2020' and 1 "2/16/2020') so it should highlight all of the rows of the ID = 2.

Please note that there might be cases in which different IDs use the same set of dates. e.g.:

```
ID  Date
1   1/1/2020
1   1/1/2020
1   1/1/2020
2   1/1/2020
2   1/16/2020
2   1/1/2020
```

In the case above, it should highlight only the rows that have ID = 2 since there's different dates for that ID (2 '1/1/2020' and 1 '1/16/2020').

Edit: This was achieved, without creating a macro, by using Conditional Formatting.

Comment: I don't think you can use `ColumnDifferences` for this. You could use conditional formatting with COUNTIFS but that might slow down your sheet. Or you could recreate similar logic using an array and looping.

Comment: Can you explain why (*"but in the ID 2, there's different dates so it should highlight all of the rows for that ID."*) all rows should be highlighted? In `ID 2 ` the date `2/2/2020` is a duplicate. Please clarify.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ - I think that there can only be one unique combination of ID and Date.

Comment: @BigBen The only unique combination for me is `2   2/16/2020` that's the only one to highlight. All others are duplicates.

Comment: I meant - for each ID, even if there are duplicate rows, there only must be one combination of ID and Date. For ID `1`, there is only one corresponding date, `1/1/2020`. But ID `2` has two different dates associated with it @Pᴇʜ. That's how I understand the question.

Comment: Ah so you mean something like `=COUNTIFS(A:A,A:A,B:B,B:B)<>COUNTIF(A:A,A:A)`? Or conditional formatting `=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A1,$B:$B,$B1)<>COUNTIF($A:$A,$A1)`

Comment: `=COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,B:B,"<>"&B1)>0` should do it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answers! Sorry about the example, it seems like it didn't arrange well. There are 2 columns (ID, Dates). I have 3 rows with the same ID but 1 of those 3 rows has a different date than the other 2, then I would need the macro to highlight those 3 cells. The purpose of this macro is to identify IDs that don't have the same dates in the date column!

Comment: @BigBen exactly! The only Unique combination is ID = 2, Date = 2/16/2020 so there's 1 row in the ID= 2 group that has a different value so I would need it to highlight all of the ID= 2 Group, I hope that is clear enough!

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: Sorry I just noticed that you already posted that as a comment. I deleted my answer. Sincere apologies...

Comment: @SiddharthRout Well, it's a good answer why don't you just keep it. It is a solution to the issue.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thank you for your help!

This sounds like it would work but what if 2 IDs use the same date? Lets say that by coincidence 2 IDs must have the same date, then the conditional format would highlight all of the cells regardless of the ID.

ID Date 1 2/2/2020 1 2/2/2020 1 2/2/2020 2 2/2/2020 2 2/3/2020 2 2/2/2020

Do you think this can be avoided using conditional format as well?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: No it is your answer. Feel free to post it :)

Comment: `what if 2 IDs use the same date?` @MichaelMurillo: In that case try the conditional formatting with this formula `=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$7,$A2)<>SUMPRODUCT(IF(CONCATENATE($A$2:$A$7,"--",$B$2:$B$7)=$A2&"--"&$B2,1,0))`

Comment: @SiddharthRout This is what I was looking for. Thank you so much for your help, I had no idea that you could so such things with conditional format. 
Have a great day!

Comment: you or @Pᴇʜ can post and answer then. It is a good question and certainly deserves an answer

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thanks, but since the actual question changed again and I didn't get the meaning of the last change, I don't know what to answer anymore ^^ I didn't get what the actual goal is. So if we want to make this a good question/answer someone should also edit the question to some clear meaningful requirement. I'm not sure about what should be highlighted and what shouldn't.

Comment: I'll change the question :) Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the ID case of 1, it shouldn't highlight anything but in the ID 2, there's different dates so it should highlight all of the rows for that ID.

No VBA required. Use **Home Tab - Conditional Formatting**

Select your range and use `Use a formula to determine which cells to format` and use the below formula. I am taking `$A$2:$B$7` for demonstration purpose. Change as applicable.

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$7,$A2)<>COUNTIF($B$2:$B$7,$B2)
```

[image]

If you still want VBA then simply record a macro and perform the above steps. You will get the code which you can edit to suit your needs.

> @SiddharthRout Thank you for your help! This sounds like it would work but what if 2 IDs use the same date? Lets say that by coincidence 2 IDs must have the same date, then the conditional format would highlight all of the cells regardless of the ID. ID Date 1 2/2/2020 1 2/2/2020 1 2/2/2020 2 2/2/2020 2 2/3/2020 2 2/2/2020 Do you think this can be avoided using conditional format as well? – Michael Murillo 14 hours ago

In such a case, the above formula will not work. Try the conditional formatting with this formula

`=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$7,$A2)<>SUMPRODUCT(IF(CONCATENATE($A$2:$A$7,"--",$B$2:$B$7)=$A2&"--"&$B2,1,0))`

What this formula does is checks for the count of `ID` in Column `A` and matches it with count of text created by concatenation of Column `A` and Column `B`.

[image]